# python how to link sublist together in a list which describe a tree

Tags: python, tree

For example list =[[1,0],[2,1],[6,2],[7,6],[7,8],[15,13],[8,15]]
shows tree

```
     _7_
   _6   8_ 
 _2      _15
```

how to get a new list contain all these number.
like the example list =

> [[1,0],[2,1],[6,2],[7,6],[7,8],[15,13],[8,15]]

the output will be new_list=[0,1,2,6,7,8,15,13] (order not important)
My biggest problem is to link [6,2],[7,6],[7,8],[8,15] together

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. What are you asking?

Comment: What you seem to be asking is an implementation of a Depth-First-Search algorithm. I would use an auxiliary Tree class to represent that.

Comment: I'm trying to get all the nodes(numbers) given in the list and put them in a new_list

Answer (score 2):

simple, if order doesn't matter:

```
 l =[[1,0],[2,1],[6,2],[7,6],[7,8],[15,13],[8,15]]
 # flatten list
 t = sum(l,[])
 # transform in a set removing duplicate values
 # otherwise if u want to keep the order you have to use an OrderedDict  
 list(set(t)) # [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving Tree and Graph Theory aside:

```
list =[[1,0],[2,1],[6,2],[7,6],[7,8],[15,13],[8,15]]

uniq = {}

for i in list:
  uniq.update({i[0]: True, i[1]: True})

print(uniq.keys())

>>> [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 13, 15]
```

---

Using python `set`:

```
list =[[1,0],[2,1],[6,2],[7,6],[7,8],[15,13],[8,15]]

uniq = set()

for i in list:
  uniq.add(i[0])
  uniq.add(i[1])

print uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

if the order is not important, you can loop through the `list` and sub-`list` and check if element is not in `new_list`:

```
list = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [6, 2], [7, 6], [7, 8], [15, 13], [8, 15]]
    new_list = []
    for sub in list:
        for elem in sub:
            if elem not in new_list:
                new_list.append(elem)
    print new_list
```

output:

```
[1, 0, 2, 6, 7, 8, 15, 13]
```